# Visual Studio 2010 custom output path for references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build-process

I have VS2010 project with several third-party references. Is there any way to automatically output these references to `$(OutputPath)\Libraries` instead of just `$(OutputPath)`?

Right now I have a custom `AfterBuild` target which looks like this,

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <LibFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\lib\dotnetzip-1.9\Release\Ionic.Zip.dll" />
    <LibFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\lib\ninject-2.2.0.0\Ninject.dll" />
    <LibFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\lib\nlog-2.0.0.2000\NLog.dll" />
    <LibFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\lib\nlog-2.0.0.2000\NLog.Extended.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(LibFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\Libraries" />
</Target>
```

However this gets tiring since I have to manually add references to `@(LibFiles)` when adding a reference in VS.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <LibFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\lib\**\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild" Inputs="@(LibFiles)">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(LibFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\Libraries" />
</Target>
```

Pros:

1. you don't have to modify AfterBuild target everytime you add new
   reference into your projects
2. libraries are copied only once or if datetime of any of files in
   @(LibFiles) is changed (after update)

Cons:

1. you will have more dlls in Libraries folder, I guess. But you can filter them using Exclude="$(SolutionDir)\lib\****\Debug\*.dll" for example